# Saving song from music app IOS7?

Tags: ios

Is it possible to save a song imported from the Music app in the local directory?

I found this code:

```
MPMediaPickerController *mediaPicker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeMusic];
mediaPicker.delegate = self;
mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = YES;
[self presentViewController:mediaPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But I am not actually sure if developers have permission to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't save the data, but you can save the metadata. Notably, you want to save the `MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID` property of a `MPMediaItem`. You should prepare your app for the possibility that this saved item is not there though, due to being removed from the device manually, or via synching.

[Here is a list](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008211-CH1-SW22) of the general metadata properties available on an `MPMediaItem`, where it says

> The value of the MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID identifier persists across application launches and across syncs that do not change the sync status of the media item. The value is not guaranteed to persist across a sync/unsync/sync cycle.

Comment: Even though this appears to be generally correct, there appears to be a workaround to achieve what the OP was asking for - see https://github.com/tapsquare/TSLibraryImport. I must admit though that I did not test this on iOS7.